# GeoJSON MultiPolygon Inversion Works for All Federal Districts of Russia Except Siberia in D3.js Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, coordinates, geojson

I'm working on a map visualization using D3.js and GeoJSON data for Russian federal districts. The goal is to  display each district as a filled polygon fill to highlight certain areas.

I followed the advice from this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897712/16518234) to invert the polygons, applying this transformation globally to each district:

```
[
  [0, 90], [180, 90], [180, -90], [0, -90], [-180, -90], [-180, 0], [-180, 90], [0, 90]
]
```

This approach worked well for all districts except showing a weird line for the Siberian Federal District on the top left [image]

I tried to play with the transformation array (flipping, changing order, scaling) but haven't succeed to fix it.

Would appreciate any help!

Component code:

```
function Map({
  statistics,
  style = {},
  colorsForScale = ["#F4F3EE", "#969AFF", "#000"]
}) {
  useEffect(() => {}, [statistics]);

  // Map
  const [regionDescription, setRegionDescription] = useState("");
  const [regionValue, setRegionValue] = useState("");

  const { language } = useLanguage();
  const [translations, setTranslations] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTranslations()
      .then((data) => {
        setTranslations(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {})
      .finally(() => {});
  }, []);

  const projection = d3geo
    .geoConicConformal()
    .scale(300)
    .center([54, 44])
    .rotate([-110, 0]);

  console.log('projection',projection)  
  const path = d3geo.geoPath().projection(projection);
  console.log('path',path)
  const values = statistics.map((item) => item.value);
  const min = Math.min(0);
  const max = Math.max(100);

  const getScale = () => {
    return [min, (min + max) / 2, max];
  };

  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear(getScale(), colorsForScale);

  const mapElements = useMemo(() => {
    if (statistics.length > 0) {
      console.log('geoData.features',geoData.features)
      return geoData.features.map((d, index) => {

        const pathD = path(d);
        if (!pathD) return null; // Skip if path is not defined

        const relevantStatistics = statistics.filter(
          (item) => item.name === d.properties.name
        )[0];
        const color = relevantStatistics
          ? colorScale(relevantStatistics?.value)
          : "lightgrey";
        return (
          <path
            key={"map-element-" + d.properties.name}
            name={d.properties.name}
            d={path(d)}
            fill= {color}
            stroke="#0e1724"
            strokeWidth="0.5"
            strokeOpacity="0.5"
            opacity="0.9"
            onMouseEnter={(e) => {
              d3.select(e.target).attr("opacity", 1);
            
              if (language === "ru") {
                setRegionDescription(relevantStatistics.name);
              } else {
                const translation = translations.find(
                  (t) => t.name_ru === relevantStatistics.name
                );
                setRegionDescription(
                  translation ? translation.name_en : relevantStatistics.name
                );
              }
              setRegionValue(Math.round(relevantStatistics.value));
            }}
            onMouseOut={(e) => {
              d3.select(e.target).attr("opacity", 0.9);
              setRegionDescription("");
              setRegionValue("");
            }}
          />
        );
      });
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <p>No map data.</p>
        </>
      );
    }
  }, [geoData, statistics]);

  // Legend
  const mapTooltip = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapTooltip.current) return;
  }, [mapTooltip]);

  const setTooltipPosition = (x, y) => {
    if (!mapTooltip.current) return;
    let newX = x - mapTooltip.current.offsetWidth / 2;
    newX = Math.max(newX, 0);
    mapTooltip.current.style.transform = `translate(${newX}px, ${y + 12}px)`;
  };

  if (statistics) {
    return (
      <div
        onPointerMove={(ev) => {
          setTooltipPosition(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
        }}
        style={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-block", ...style }}
      >
        <svg className="map">
          <g className="map">{mapElements}</g>
        </svg>

        <div
          className={`map-tooltip ${!regionDescription && "hidden"}`}
          ref={mapTooltip}
        >
          {/* <div className="tip"></div> */}
          {regionDescription && (
            <>
              <h3>{regionDescription}</h3>
              <h1>{regionValue}%</h1>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <></>;
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Note that the array is not a "transformation", it just sets up a giant bounding box that subsequent shapes are considered "cutouts" of because they lie fully inside of it. Except for Siberia, which crosses that bounding box's edge. Why do you need to invert anything if you want filled shapes, though? That's the default D3 behaviour already.

Comment: Also wondering why you need to invert anything - if you fill the shapes with a constant color, then the boundary of the antimeridian won’t be visible. Though there are tools that can merge the two sides of the sliced territory. There are likely alternative existing datasets that have the data properly spherically projected rather.  You could adjust the bounding box, but this seems more work and doesn’t solve the anti-meridian problem on land (just on water).